# Passing a blank value using javascript of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to pass a "blank" value to a hidden input type?  And when I say blank, I mean an actual whitespace character or something?

For example, I have this select:

```
    <select name="Sample">
    <option value="BB515_Hu_CD3" >BB515, Human CD3</option>
    </select>
```

On one form, it's a drop down where a user selects the option. Upon submission, the value of the option gets written to the "Sample" database field.

On another web form that writes to the same database and doesn't have Sample select, I would like to pass a blank value so that the current value in the database field is deleted and empty.

```
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="Sample" />
```

I can add a dash '-' in the value and then it will overwrite the BB515_Hu_CD3 value with a dash, but I would rather have a blank field then a dash in it.  Keeping value="" will just keep the original data which I don't want.

Each form has contact matching enabled on it via email address.  So if I use the same email for both forms, the original form submission data will be updated with the second form submission data.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Keeping value="" will just keep the original data which I don't want.` It shouldn't unless your code that writes to the database ignores empty strings. Can we see your server-side code?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you asking how to use JQuery to set the value of the field?

Comment: Why would you pass a `blank` value... Whats the sense?

Comment: What language are you using to write to the database?  SQL?  Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

That hidden field should be in the post array as an empty variable.

On the server side you can just insert into the database whatever value is given for Sample.

For example if you have this:

```
<select name="Sample">
    <option value="" >Choose Sample</option>
    <option value="BB515_Hu_CD3" >BB515, Human CD3</option>
    </select>
```

or this

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="Sample" />
```

Then server side:

```
 $data['Sample'] = $_POST['Sample'];//if it is empty it will update the database with an empty string if not then it will update with the value
```

You can also use a value like - if so, then do this:

```
if(!empty($_POST['Sample']) && $_POST['Sample'] == '-')
{
$data['Sample'] = "";
}
```

For the javascript/jquery portion:

```
// this is the id of the form
$("#idForm").submit(function() {

    var url = "path/to/your/script.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#idForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements automatically
           success: function(data)
           {
               alert(data); // show response from the php script.
           }
         });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

alert(data); is where you would handle the response from the server

If it does not work like this in your current code we may need to see the code.  Validation libraries or javascript may do some strange things.